# How can I remove a pcap header?

Tags: pcap

I recorded a pcap file with wireshark and now I want to get rid of the pcap header.

Means: I want my .pcap file to start directly with my ethernet frame (source & destination MAC) and get rid of the PCAP headers.

Answer (score 0):

libpcap files only have [a 24 bytes header](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat#Global_Header) at the start. The following command does the trick:

```
cat in.pcap | tail -c +25 > out.pcap
```